# How do I input some logic when creating nested records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-many

I have bees as nested attribute for beehive, linked through beelink

bees

```
has_many :beehives through :beelinks
```

and beehives

```
has_many :bees, through: :beelinks
```

and of course beelinks

```
belongs_to :bees
belongs_to :beehives
```

bee has a field called description

I have nested form for beehive with 5 bee description fields, and so when I create the beehive, I save the bees and the beehive using

```
@beehive.save
```

A bee can only exist once in the database. However, if the new beehive has an existing bee (description of new bee and existing bee matches), I'd like to create the beelink using the existing bee rather than to reject the creation of the bee (and hence the beehive)

since

```
@beehive.save
```

is saving beehive and bees, where do I place

```
@beehive.bees.each do |b|
  Bee.where(description: b.description).first_or_create!
  Beelink.where(bee: b, beehive: @beehive).create
end
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to destroy the beautiful

```
@beehive.save
```

to make this terrible monster.

```
@beehive = Beehive.create(attributes: params[:beehive][:attribues])
params[:beehive][:bees_attributes].each do |key, hash|
  hash.each do |k, description|
    bee = Bee.where(description: description).first_or_create
    Beelink.where(bee: bee, beehive: @beehive).first_or_create
  end
end
```

If anybody has a better solution, I'll gladly take it